# A title for upper part and another for lower part of a tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I need to define a tcolorbox with a title for the upper part and another for the lower part as in the image. But I can't find a solution to **properly** insert the fancy "POR QUE?" on the lower part of tcolorbox.

[image]

I used 'underlay boxed title' as in the code below, but I don't know **how to refer to an upper corner of the lower part of the box** to use in the second part of the underlay boxed title. As it is in the code below, the second title has an absolute position in the box. So, if the upper part gets bigger, then its text would be over the "POR QUE".

```
\newtcolorbox{openningbox}{enhanced, jigsaw, colback=white, colframe=white, lower separated=false, 
\titlefont, title={O QU\^E?},
boxed title style={empty,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt}, 
attach boxed title to top left={ yshift=-10 mm},
underlay boxed title={
\fill[green] ($(title.north west) + (0,-7mm)$) coordinate (x1) -- ++ (23 mm,0mm) arc [start angle=-90, end angle=90, x radius=3mm, y radius=3mm] coordinate (x2) -- ++ (-23 mm,0mm) -- cycle;

\fill[green] ($(frame.north west) + (0,-53mm)$) coordinate (c1) -- ++ (23 mm,0mm) arc [start angle=-90, end angle=90, x radius=3mm, y radius=3mm] coordinate (c2) -- ++ (-23 mm,0mm) -- cycle;
\node[right] at ($(c1)!0.5!(c2)+ (-8mm,0)$) {POR QU\^E?};}
}
```

Any idea about how to get it done?

Comment: Please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to make sure that your question receives the desired attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `before upper` and `before lower` to insert subtitles.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{openningbox}{
    frame empty,
    arc = 8pt,
    lower separated = false,
    before upper = \tcbsubtitle{O QU\^E?},
    before lower = \tcbsubtitle{POR QU\^E?},
    font upper = \sffamily,
    font lower = \sffamily,
    sharp corners = north,
    subtitle style = {
      frame empty,
      fontupper = \sffamily\bfseries,
      colback = cyan!90!black,
      coltext = black!70,
      width = 3cm,
      arc = 8pt,
      rounded corners = east
    }
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{openningbox}{}
  \lipsum*[1]
  \tcblower
  \lipsum*[2]
\end{openningbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know 'before upper' and 'before lower'!