# How to split a box horizontally in tcolorbox?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I have the following custom environment setup:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newtcolorbox{titlebox}[5]{enhanced,center,colframe=black,colback=white,boxrule={#3},arc={#2},auto outer arc,%
 breakable,pad at break*=5pt,vfill before first,before={\par\medskip\noindent},after={\par\medskip},top=12pt,left=4pt,%
 enlarge top by=7pt,%enlarge bottom by=7pt,%
 title={\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries #1}, varwidth boxed title*=-30pt,
 attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-10pt,xshift=10pt}, coltitle=black,
 boxed title style={colback=white,boxrule={#5},arc={#4},auto outer arc}
 }
 
 \newenvironment{experiment}[1]{%
 \begin{small}\begin{titlebox}{{\normalfont \textbf{Experiment}} \normalfont #1}{2.5pt}{1pt}{3.5pt}{1pt}}
 {\end{titlebox}\end{small}}

\begin{document}
\begin{environment}{Real}{Ideal}
Left text & Right Text
\end{environment}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I want to modify my environment in such a way that it splits the box horizontally into two halves of equal size, and on the left of both sides I want to have the text "Experiment" followed by the given input. I also want to be able to write on both sides of the divided box somehow. Optionally, there should be a vertical bar where the division of the box into two parts happens. Any ideas how to do that? Something along these lines (so the current box kind of replicated to have two parts):

[image]

Comment: Can you add a sketch how the result should look like?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added a picture now, sorry my drawing skills are not good, but basically two have kind of two copies of the box I have now, and to be able to write on left and right halves.

Comment: Thanks! This makes your question much clearer!

Comment: Compare https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685636/47927

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the same approach as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433142/36296 and use subtitles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newtcolorbox{openningbox}[2]{
    colback = white,
    colframe = black,
    before upper = \tcbsubtitle{\tikz{\node[draw=black,fill=white,thick,rounded corners,font=\bfseries\color{black}]{Experiment #1};}},
    before lower = \tcbsubtitle{\tikz{\node[draw=black,fill=white,thick,rounded corners,font=\bfseries\color{black}]{Experiment #2};}},
    subtitle style = {
      enhanced,
      interior hidden,
      frame hidden,
      top=-0.8cm,
    },
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align = top,
    enhanced,
    segmentation style = {solid,line width=2pt}
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{openningbox}{Real}{Ideal}
  \lipsum*[1]
  \tcblower
  \lipsum*[2]
\end{openningbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can I somehow make the dashed line solid like the border or just remove it?

Comment: @pixel The tcolorbox documentation has example how to change the line style. Search for `segmentation style`

Comment: Adding something like `segmentation style=solid` at the end of your `newtcolorbox` does not do anything.

Comment: @pixel See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely now. One final question, it it possible to push subtitles and start of the text a bit to the left? More precisely, to change the margins from top bottom and down?

Comment: @pixel If you have a new question, please ask a new question

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687282/how-to-change-margins-in-tcolorbox