# How to change margins in tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I have the following box, but I want to change a bit the margins from all the sides. Is it possible to set custom margins (i.e., control where the text starts and ends)? Also I want to move the subtitles a bit to the left. Note that the text should start before the subtitles, as currently start of text and subtitles are aligned.

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

 \newtcolorbox{openningbox}[2]{
    colback = white,
    colframe = black,
    before upper = \tcbsubtitle{\tikz{\node[draw=black,fill=white,line width=1pt,rounded corners=3.5pt,font=\bfseries\color{black}]{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\normalfont ~~\textbf{Experiment} #1~~};}},
    before lower = \tcbsubtitle{\tikz{\node[draw=black,fill=white,line width=1pt,rounded corners=3.5pt,font=\bfseries\color{black}]{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\normalfont ~~\textbf{Experiment} #2~~};}},
    subtitle style = {
      enhanced,
      interior hidden,
      frame hidden,
      top=-0.8cm
    },
    boxrule=1pt,
    arc=2.5pt,
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align = top,
    enhanced,
    segmentation style = {solid,line width=1pt}
  }



\begin{document}

\begin{openningbox}{Real}{Ideal}
  \lipsum*[1]
  \tcblower
  \lipsum*[2]
\end{openningbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at section "2 Quick Reference" of the tcolorbox documentation.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Apparently setting just `left` also moves only the text on the left part of the box, and does not affect the right column that much.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Is it possible to set the distance to segmentation line from left and right somehow?

Comment: About segmentation. You have some examples in page 156 and 158. You can draw it with some shift from `segmentation` anchors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative definition of OP's `openningbox`.

Main changes are:

- Title and subtitle are replaced with an `attach boxed title to top` and a `\node` added through an `overlay` option. We could also use two overlay options to be sure that geometry of title is the same.
- Text margins are adjusted with `left` and `right` parameters. Inner gap between side by side paragraphs is fixed with `sidebyside gap`.
- `sidebyside align=top` works with the help of `yshift*` option in boxed title.
- segmentation rule can be shortened with `shorten` options in its style.

The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

 \newtcolorbox{openningbox}[2]{
     enhanced,
    colback = white,
    colframe = black,
     title = {\textbf{Experiment}~#1~~},
     coltitle=black,
     boxed title style={colframe=black, colback=white},
     attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2, xshift=5mm},
     overlay={\node[rounded corners=2.5pt, line width=1pt, draw, anchor=west, fill=white, inner xsep=3mm, inner ysep=1.25mm] at ([xshift=5mm]segmentation.north) {\textbf{Experiment}~#2~~};},
    boxrule=1pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=2mm,
    right=2mm,
    sidebyside gap=4mm,
    arc=2.5pt,
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align = top,
    enhanced,
    segmentation style = {solid,line width=1pt, shorten >=1cm, shorten <=1cm}
  }



\begin{document}

\begin{openningbox}{Real}{Ideal}
  \lipsum*[1]
  \tcblower
  \lipsum*[2]
\end{openningbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]